Stripe price unit_amount update, Stripe Dashboard vs API
I read it's not possible to update the unit_amount of a price object, but I can update it from the Stripe dashboard.
Does it mean if I subscribe to price.updated from a webhook I will receive the updated unit_amount for the price, or it is completely unhandled by the Stripe API?
Also, why is updating prices only possible form the dashboard and not from the API?

My understanding is that the Dashboard lets you edit the amount before a Price has been used(after it's used it can't be edited), for convenience in the frontend flows. The API doesn't do that today. The webhook question can likely be answered really quickly by just doing the edit in the Dashboard and looking at what events appear in the Developers section!
